# Character Input Not Halting Program

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I am new to Python and am encountering an error when I use the following:

```
name = input("Would you please enter your name: ")
age = int(input("Would you please enter your age: "))
year = str((2017 - age)+100)
print("Your name is " + name + "and you will turn 100 years old in the year "  + year)
```

When I open Python 3.5.3 from the Command Prompt (Windows 10), and I copy and paste this code from my notepad, the first lines appear as:

```
>>>> name = input("Would you please enter your name: ")
Would you please enter your name: age = int(input("Would you please enter 
your age: "))
```

How do I circumvent this issue? From what I've read the program is supposed to break after encountering "`input`."

For reference I am starting to work through problem  1 from http://www.practicepython.org/exercise/2014/01/29/01-character-input.html

Comment: the second line you paste is seen as the input of the first one. You have to paste that line by line or run from within a .py script.

Answer (score 0):

In Python interactive mode lines are executed at each line break so in your example is `name` is assigned the value of the string `'age = int(input("Would you please enter your age: "))'`.

If you want to copy the full code into the interactive prompt and have it execute only after all lines then you have to [add `;\`](https://superuser.com/a/614368) to the end of each line before you copy the text. The `;` shows the assignment has ended but the `\` indicates line continuation so the code isn't executed immediately:

```
>>> name = input("Would you please enter your name: ") ;\
... age = int(input("Would you please enter your age: "))
Would you please enter your name: NicolausCopernicolaus
Would you please enter your age: 29
>>> name
'NicolausCopernicolaus'
>>> age
29
```